# packet tracking to find blockage

Tags: linux, networking

Somewhere, something is blocking transmission between my LAN and my internet-connected server. What can I use to find the blockage point, where the packets are lost? The LAN network card, the server network card, or what?

The physical arrangements (HDs, network cards, etc.) for the server have worked for years but an upgrade of the server's OS has produced the problem.

Comment: Try using `traceroute` to find where packets are being dropped.

Comment: [traceroute] from a computer in the LAN doesn't work. I get an 'unknown host' message. [traceroute] from an outside computer works; no packet stoppage. So the packets are stopped in the LAN at or before they get out of the external interface of the server. The blockage is somewhere local.

Comment: Unknown host indicates a name resolution issue. Try dig or nslookup for the hostname. Alternatively, resolve the hostname elsewhere and traceroute to the resolved IP.